# Program still runs on one thread using par_iter and par_extend

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, iterator, rayon

I'm trying to parallelize a portion of my code, and despite it using `rayon` and the parallel iterators `par_iter()` and `par_extend()`, it still looks like it runs on a single thread.

I simply create a vector of `i32`, fill it up with a lot of values, and then move these values into a `collections::HashSet` of integers.

My single threaded code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i64> = (0..100_000_000).collect();

    let mut my_set: HashSet<i64> = HashSet::new();
    let st = std::time::Instant::now();
    my_set.extend(
        my_vec.iter().map(|x| x*(x+3)/77+44741)  // this is supposed to take a while to compute
    );
    let dur = st.elapsed();
    println!("{:?}", dur);

}
```

Running time is around `8.86 s` in average.
Here is the code using parallel iterators:

```
extern crate rayon;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i64> = (0..100_000_000).collect();

    let mut my_set: HashSet<i64> = HashSet::new();
    let st = std::time::Instant::now();
    my_set.par_extend(
        my_vec.par_iter().map(|x| x*(x+3)/77+44741) // this is supposed to take a while to compute
    );
    let dur = st.elapsed();
    println!("{:?}", dur);
}
```

The average running time for the 'parallel' version is almost the same (`8.62 s`), and the cpu monitor clearly shows that a single cpu is working at 100% while the others just wait.

Do you know what I did wrong, or did not understand?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Thanks for the remark, it's edited, it looks more 'rusthonic' now.

Comment: I think that it works well: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=53958a37fb57365a9609c210aede3706 Rayon is slower, which is an expected result

Comment: I think that the CPU that runs at 100% is the rayon runtime. Since the calculation is faster than a context switch, the other threads have a low charge.

Comment: Ok .... it would be a good sign, since the objects I work with in my project are much bigger, and the expression `|x| x*(x+3)/77+44741` is actually a big search function which takes several dozens milliseconds. I'll try on my project then, thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simulation is not right because your calculation is actually fast, so fast that it is faster by several orders of magnitude than a thread context switch. Your core at 100% is likely the rayon runtime, while the other cores are waiting for it.

If you actually replace your computation by a sleep, the results are as you expect:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.1.0
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    fn slow(i: &i64) -> i64 {
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(5));

        *i
    }

    let my_vec: Vec<i64> = (0..100).collect();

    let mut my_set: HashSet<i64> = HashSet::new();

    let st = std::time::Instant::now();
    my_set.extend(
        my_vec.iter().map(slow)  // this is supposed to take a while to compute
    );
    let dur = st.elapsed();
    println!("Regular: {:?}", dur);

    let st = std::time::Instant::now();
    my_set.par_extend(
        my_vec.par_iter().map(slow) // this is supposed to take a while to compute
    );
    let dur = st.elapsed();
    println!("Rayon: {:?}", dur);
}
```

Output:

```
Regular: 685.670791ms
Rayon: 316.733253ms
```

When you try to optimize your code, you must carefully benchmark it because sometimes, when you parallelize your code, that can make it slower.